# Motion web control interface - which motion.conf file does it use?

Tags: motion, permissions

When i use the web interface (mmaltest) on motion it doesn't appear to change the operation of motion.

It remembers the values i change on the web interface, so looks like it's working, but is's not transferring the values across when i look using terminal.

1) where does motion look for its motion.conf file? I've seen a conf file in etc/motion.conf and /ect/motion/motion.conf; which one is motion using?

2)if motion runs as user motion, and the permissions are set to 0777 can user pi see /change the motion.conf file?

Comment: I had the same issue with the web interface. I edited /etc/motion/motion.conf directly and it worked.

Comment: Thanks iceman, it's reassuring that someone else had problems with motion's web interface; i thought it must be something i was doing wrong! has anyone else manage to change a setting, using the web interface, and see the change in the motion.conf file?

Comment: Can you elaborate?
I don't know if it's the same issue but I can;t get motion to start in daemon no matter what I tried. I ave already edited etc/default/motion & etc/motion/motion.conf to no avail. Seems like a permissions problem. I'm a complete newbie to Rpi so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make the file "motion.conf" user, owner and group to "motion" then it let me control it using the web interface.